# Trying to use whois in python but getting file not found error in windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, whois

I am trying to use whois but getting this error:

[image]

I have also installed https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/whois and it is working fine in my cmd but when I try it with python it shows the above error.

[image]

I have installed both python-whois and whois using the below commands but still getting the same error.

```
pip install python-whois
pip install whois
```

Edit: whois.whois() is not working it shows the below error:

AttributeError: module 'whois' has no attribute 'whois'

So I used whois.query() instead

My Code and output:
[image]

Comment: Looks like you forgot to post your Python code

Comment: Hey Vlad, I have added my code with the output screenshot

Answer (score 1):

If you have correctly installed python-whois into your Python runtime environment then, for example:

```
import whois

wd = whois.whois('google.com')
```

Then, for example:

```
print(*wd['domain_name'])
```

**Output:**

```
GOOGLE.COM google.com
```

Comment: Actually, whois.whois('google.com') is not working it shows this error : AttributeError: module 'whois' has no attribute 'whois'. So I used whois.query() instead

Comment: @TusharUpadhayay I think you have a file named whois.py in your current working directory which would conflict with your installation of whois-python. Rename it and try again